# How to get Azure webapp config appsettings using Az PowerShell module

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

For certain reasons I cannot use

```
az webapp config appsettings list -n appxxx-dfpg-dev4-web-eastus2-gateway-apsvc -g appxxx-dfpg-dev4-web-eastus2
```

Instead I want to achieve the same result by using Az PowerShell module, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this powershell cmdlet [Get-AzWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azwebapp?view=azps-4.3.0).

The sample code:

```
 $myapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "resource_group_name" -Name "azure_webapp_name"

 $myapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
```

The test result:

[image]